# Nativewind not taking effect?

Tags: react-native, nativewind

I'm trying to use nativewind with a React Native component.

It works if I apply the className line to a Text directly but it doesn't work like this.

Follow up question: is it ok to use both nativewind and styleSheet?

```
   <View className="text-lg" style={styles.row}>
        <View>
          <Text>text</Text>
          <Text>text</Text>
        </View>
   </View>
```

I tried downgrading Tailwind dev dependency.